# How to setup DHCP client to preferentially choose a DHCP server over the other

Tags: 18.04, systemd, dhcp

I have a modem with a DHCP server and a Gateway Ubuntu Linux server with its own DHCP server on the same LAN subnet. The idea is that while the Gateway DHCP server is available the dhcp client on the ubuntu machines connected to the LAN should preferentially take their IP address from this DHCP server. When the Gateway goes down they should take the IP from the modem which has its own DHCP server running.

Any suggestions on how to setup a priority for the DHCP servers? or solve this another way (failover has to be automatic)

Comment: You would need to split the DHCP scope and divide it between the server and the modem, in order to avoid IP address conflicts. As for priority, I have seen DHCP servers that were configured to wait 1 second before responding to the DHCP request. Don't know if that is possible with your modem. Otherwise, DHCP is a completely first-come-first-serve protocol.

Comment: Thanks @Jos, Even if DHCP itself is a first come first serve protocol, a DHCP client 'could' prioritize to using the IP returned by a higher priority DHCP server (priority can be an configuration to the DHCP client). If the IP has been received from the higher priority server, change to the IP received from it. If the IP received is from a lower priority server, keep the IP you already have.

Comment: Currently I know of no client that implements server priority in a configurable way. You would need to code your own DHCP client, I suppose.

Comment: To the original coders, enhancing an existing DHCP client would be a very straightforward thing. Guess I will head over to the systemd-network folks (who will probably reject it anyways for updating the protocol)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I am in the same boat.  I guess that the DHCP server on the modem is very limited in features (mine does not allow to specify a PXE or bootp server, for example).  You want the gateway DHCP servers to be prioritized for features but fall back to the modem DHCP server for resilience, right?

I believe you need to address this the other way around. Why would you want to go around and configure all your clients?  Then you might as well give them a fixed IP.  This should be automatic and transparent for all clients in the LAN.

Does the modem DHCP server allow you to specify a reply-delay?  If so, you're already golden.  Set the gateway DHCP server to respond immediately and the modem DHCP server with a 3-second delay.  Have the former serve IP in the range of 192.168.7.50-59 and the latter in 192.168.7.100-150, for example.

If the modem DHCP server has no reply-delay option, then go ahead and configure your Ubuntu gateway DHCP server for a 3-second delay.  If you use dnsmasq, the relevant configuration knob is `--dhcp-reply-delay`.  Furthermore, limit the IP numbers handed out by the modem to a short TTL.  Then you periodically need to run a DCHP client request from the Ubuntu gateway machine to clog the usable IP space on the modem DHCP pool.  Then, when a request comes from a real client only the gateway DHCP server will have any IP numbers available to serve.  When the Ubuntu machine goes down, the IP space it was hogging will slowly get released (due to the low TTL) and be available for requests from ordinary machines.